# Cassandra Java request

Tags: java, cassandra

I trying to execute a simple request in Java with Cassandra database but I don't understand my example it don't work :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                          .addContactPoints("127.0.0.1")
                          .build();
        Session session = cluster.connect("test");

        ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM datatest");
        for ( Row row : results ) {
            System.out.println(row.getString("name"));
        }
    }

}
```

When I execute my code I have this error :

```
[main] INFO com.datastax.driver.core.policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy - Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
[main] INFO com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is not a column defined in this metadata
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnDefinitions.getAllIdx(ColumnDefinitions.java:273)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnDefinitions.getFirstIdx(ColumnDefinitions.java:279)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedRow.getIndexOf(ArrayBackedRow.java:69)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getString(AbstractGettableData.java:137)
    at fakemillions.Test.main(Test.java:23)
```

This is my database :

[My database screenshot](http://hpics.li/9e86705)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you haven't defined a column with the name "name" in the table datatest. I haven't used  Datastax driver before, but as the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Row.html#getString(java.lang.String)) says the **IllegalArgumentException** is thrown if

> name is not part of the ResultSet this row is part of, i.e. if !this.columns().names().contains(name)

It'd be better if you provided how you created the datatest table.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a table using thrift, which contains dynamic columns, and therefore did not give explicit column definitions, then CQL by default assign the following names: `key`, `column1`, `value`. In your case it will have `column1` contain the value "name", `value` column will contain "TiTi", etc.

Think about it as this. The data is stored really as key-value pairs. CQL can't infer any column names from these key-value pairs, since there may be billions of different keys (column names) in the same row.

Here is a good guide to migrate thrift tables to cql: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3

Answer (score 1):

Try this work in my case

```
Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
Cluster cluster=builder.withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy("us-east"))).addContactPoints("127.0.0.1").build();
```